# How to remove special character with brackets from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a columns values like this 'Voice_DropRate_4G(%)' so I need to be like this in the dataframe, just remove this '(%)' from all columns names, and I want also to replace the upper case letter with a lower case letter to be the final result like this in the data frame `voice_droprate_4g`

as I tried to use this line to remove unneeded characters by using `Replace` function like the below code..

`dft.columns = dft.columns.str.replace('(%)', '')`

but it's doesn't remove the brackets it's shows me like this 'Voice_DropRate_4G()', So any one have any Idea how to solve this issue....

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `()` are special regex chars you need escape it by `\`, then convert values to lowercase:

```
dft.columns = dft.columns.str.replace('\(%\)', '').str.lower()
```

**Sample**:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Voice_DropRate_4G(%)','Voice_DropRate_5G(%)'])
dft.columns = dft.columns.str.replace('\(%\)', '').str.lower()
print (dft)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [voice_droprate_4g, voice_droprate_5g]
Index: []
```

Comment: @MahmoudHarooney - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)